How to calculate the Exhaust flow rate of a 950hp 410Ci motor?
Max Rpm is 9000,
Exhaust port diameter 37.846mm ,
4 into 1, 1 7/8"-2"-3.5" stepped header.
1.205kg/m³ air density

check out books by Judge, Chapman, Ricardo, Cummins - and many other engineering or thermodynamics textbooks. Engineering Thermodynamics Work and Heat Transfer by Rogers and Mayhew

Rogers&Mayhew not Matthew. And obviously Heywood's book. There's a whole bunch of variables OP has left out.

@GregLocock edited that as it was posted - autocorrect is not up on thermodynamicists...

A starting approximation for flow rate is as follows:
a 410 cubic inch engine will cycle through 205 cubic inches per revolution. at 9000RPM it will cycle through (205)x(9000) cubic inches per minute.
